# when i install python 3.9 on chromebook with linux penguin i still see the old version

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I am not a linux user, so this might be a basic question.

I am trying to upgrade python version from `3.5` to `3.9` on a chromebook.
The chrome book runs linux penguin (i type `uname -a` to get the version).

```
Linux penguin 5.4.67-09356-gf3ed4c0c4a31 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Sep 27 20:30:52 PDT 2020 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I have tried the following online method (replacing `3.7` for `3.9`) but it fails:
https://dev.to/serhatteker/how-to-upgrade-to-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-18-04-18-10-5hab

https://dev.to/serhatteker/how-to-upgrade-to-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-18-04-18-10-5hab

I have tried other online methods too, but they also fail so i now go back to the basics.

I have also tried this method for `miniconda`:
https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html
for both the `32` and `64` bit versions of `python` on `linux` but get the error message:

```
Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 414: /opt/miniconda3/conda.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

In particular i note that the new python version is not in the /usr/bin folder, but the old version is.

I therefore do: `sudo apt install python3.9` and see the following:

```
dlefcoe@penguin:~$ sudo apt install python3.9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'postgresql-plpython3-9.6' for regex 'python3.9'
postgresql-plpython3-9.6 is already the newest version (9.6.20-0+deb9u1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
```

This looks positive, but when i do `python` it still goes to the old version.
When i type `python3.9` the system returns:

```
-bash: python3.9: command not found
```

I presume that version 3.9 is installed somewhere (but where i don't know) or i have not installed it properly.

How can i get this working on the chromebook please ?

Answer (score 4):

The following solution works:

1. Install dependencies

   `sudo apt update`

   `sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev libsqlite3-dev wget libbz2-dev`
2. Download latest release

   `wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.0/Python-3.9.0.tgz`
3. extract file

   `tar -xf Python-3.9.0.tgz`
4. configure script

   `cd Python-3.9.0`
   `./configure --enable-optimizations`
5. build process

   `make -j 12`
6. install binaries

   `sudo make altinstall`

And then test the version with `python3.9 --version`.

The full link is here:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-9-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Presumably this will work with later versions too. So `3.9.x`.